# What are the markings in the transporters in Star Trek for?

Tags: star-trek, technology

There are always these circular spots in the transporter rooms on which the teleported people appear and where they wait for the teleportation to happen.

[image]

(Image from [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/treknology/treknology-t.htm)).

These spots don't make a lot of sense since many episodes show that it's possible to transport much bigger objects than human, and more people than there are spots for. I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: In TNG, the middle was a "spot" too, making the whole platform one big, segmented transporter.

Comment: Although not cannon, in at least one book (TOS, Great Starship Race?)  they mention that beaming from Pad to Pad is much safer, and uses much less energy. This makes a lot of sense: imagine deconstructing a car in car factory with lots of tools then reconstructing it in the desert with nothing. So, presumably, those pads help, making the process more efficient/safer/faster/etc, but are not strictly necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Star Trek - What's the Point of the Transporter Room?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/in-star-trek-whats-the-point-of-the-transporter-room)

Comment: **Based on the answer**, this seems a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5589/19561 to me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's never been officially stated, but there have been times when transportation of people close together was difficult - they had trouble separating their signals.  It's likely that the spots are designed to ensure separation of individuals, to provide easier lock-on.

It's also likely that by TNG, this is simply a tradition which no longer is absolutely needed - they show a much greater utility in their transporters than TOS ever did.

Still, like the US Marine's dress sabers, the transporter pad markings remain - for historical value, if nothing else.

Comment: Also, it is really convienent for actors as marks for scene composition.

Comment: and they look good when they go all glowy

Comment: Presumably they also act as pattern enhancers, much like the [rocket-looking ones](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pattern_enhancer) in other parts of the show. They increase the range and safety of the system.

Comment: nice. blocking dots, OghmaOsiris !