# Why did Federation starships need transporter rooms?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Star Trek - What's the Point of the Transporter Room?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/in-star-trek-whats-the-point-of-the-transporter-room)

If transporters can beam people directly from site-to-site (i.e.: straight from the surface of a planet to the bridge (as seen in [STNG S3-E3, "The Survivors"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Survivors_%28episode%29), and other episodes), why is a dedicated transporter room and pads required aboard a starship?

Comment: Point to point was 1) later technology (for constitution class), 2) still used a transporter room to house the equipment, it operates like two transports, one to the room and one back out, but without re-materializing and flushing the buffers in between.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter#.22Site-to-site.22_transport

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Site-to-site_transport

Comment: I feel like I've read this question before...

Comment: I have:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/in-star-trek-whats-the-point-of-the-transporter-room

Answer (score 1):

I recall something about energy utilization.  Most efficient was a pad-to-pad transport, less efficient was non-pad to pad (or vice-versa) and least efficient was non-pad to non-pad.  Wish I could tell you where I came across this but can't :(  Think it was in a TNG episode but can't swear to it.